# Starting Service from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver` in my application, but how do I launch the service directly from the `BroadcastReceiver`? Using

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

does not work in a `BroadcastReceiver`, any ideas?

EDIT:

> context.startService(..);

works, I forgot the context part

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Don't forget

> `context.startService(..);`

Comment: Flawless answer. Got it fixed with very little trouble reading.

Comment: Also check this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/WVoO8kQCFF0
context.startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PAUSE, null, context, MusicService.class));

Comment: Thanks a ton for the rescue...:)

Comment: What is "context" suppoed to be ?

Comment: it gives crash :- android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

Answer (score 61):

should be like that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourServiceName.class);
context.startService(i);
```

be sure to add the service to manifest.xml

Comment: Typical manifest item (goes under <application>, at same 'level' as <activity>'):    <receiver android:name=".YourServiceName"></receiver>

Comment: @ArtSwri it should be <service android:name=".YourServiceName"></service> not receiver.

Answer (score 14):

use the `context` from the `onReceive` method of your [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to start your service component.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
      context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Comment: Finally someone who cares to mention what "context" is. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Best Practice :

While creating an intent especially while starting from `BroadcastReceiver`, dont take **this** as context.
Take `context.getApplicationContext()` like below

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), classNAME);
context.getApplicationContext().startService(intent);
```

Comment: Yes. We should pass context.getApplicationContext() or else app will crash

Comment: Care to mention why pls ?

Comment: Reason for why : Context-registered receivers receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts as long as the app is running.

Comment: Still crashes for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
 try {
        Intent intentService = new Intent(context, MyNewIntentService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(intentService );
        } else {
            context.startService(intentService );
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use ContextCompat:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because a receiver's onReceive(Context, Intent) method runs on the main thread, it should execute and return quickly. If you need to perform long running work, be careful about spawning threads or starting background services because the system can kill the entire process after onReceive() returns. For more information, see Effect on process state To perform long running work, we recommend:
>
> Calling goAsync() in your receiver's onReceive() method and passing the BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult to a background thread. This keeps the broadcast active after returning from onReceive(). However, even with this approach the system expects you to finish with the broadcast very quickly (under 10 seconds). It does allow you to move work to another thread to avoid glitching the main thread.
>   Scheduling a job with the JobScheduler
>   [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#effects-on-process-state)