# Why button click of App widget does not work?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, widget, broadcastreceiver

I have tried to build a simple widget that when user clicks on a button something happen. I've searched a lot to solve the problem, but nothing happens when click on the button of my widget. In fact, after debugging, I found out that onReceive does not get called in this case.

```
class AppWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
    val WIDGET_BUTTON = "com.sahra.oms.ui.widget.WIDGET_CLICK"

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
        
        appWidgetIds?.forEach { appWidgetId ->
           updateWidget(context!!, appWidgetManager!!, appWidgetId)
       }
    }

    private fun updateWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {

        val intent = Intent(context, AppWidgetProvider::class.java)
        intent.action = WIDGET_BUTTON
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)

        val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout)
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgSync, pendingIntent)

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)

        if (WIDGET_BUTTON == intent?.action) {

           val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
           val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout)
           val watchWidget = ComponentName(context!!, Widget::class.java)

           remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtIssuanceRateTitle, "TESTING")

           appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews)
       }
    }
}
```

And, in the Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".ui.widget.AppWidgetProvider" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="com.sahra.oms.ui.widget.WIDGET_CLICK" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Have you called the start function of the broadcast receiver you want to run in the background?

Comment: I suppose if you put the receiver's declaration in the Manifest, there is no need to call it from the code.

Comment: Although you declared it on manifest yet It has not started the service in application. [How to start the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641712/starting-service-from-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: I'll check it out, tnx